# jackd with raspberry pi 3 jackd server stops

Tags: raspbian, audio, linux

I'm using jackd2 on my raspi3 with a USB sound and recording device like this one. Build is Jessie

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Adapter-External-Headphone-Speaker-Microphone/dp/B016CU2PEU/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1490876891&sr=8-2&keywords=usb+audio

I have complied a headless jackd2 using this:
https://capocasa.net/jackd-headless

Everything is seen aplay -l and arecord -l see my devices fine.

I'm using darkice to stream to a streaming server by specifying jack_auto in the /etc/darkice.conf file

The problem seems to be that after around 3-4 hours of streaming jackd stops.

I have used
sudo jackd -v -R -d alsa -d hw:1,0 -r 44100

to start the server
I have also used

jackd -P70 -p16 -t2000 -dalsa -dhw:1,0 -p2048 -n3 -r44800 -s 
with the same results

I have also tried the same build on my Ubuntu 16.0.4.2 LTS machine (virtual machine) with exactly the same results ....
I have tried streaming without jackd by using plughw:1,0 in the darkice.conf file which carries on streaming for many hours but the sound is not as good as using jackd2

In this 3-4 hours there is no streaming taking place just a connection to the streaming server
Is jackd2 supposed to timeout/stop like this after this time? 
please any help appreciated

The verbose out is below (from the Ubuntu box) but its pretty much the same on the raspi3

```
jackdmp 1.9.11
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2016 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
creating alsa driver ... hw:1,0|hw:1,0|1024|2|44100|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
configuring for 44100Hz, period = 1024 frames (23.2 ms), buffer = 2 periods
ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 16bit little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for capture
ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 16bit little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
abid@vmMaRadio01:~$ cat /home/abid/jackd.log
jackdmp 1.9.11
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2016 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
Jack: JackPosixThread::StartImp : create non RT thread
Jack: JackPosixThread::ThreadHandler : start
Jack: playback device hw:1,0
Jack: capture device hw:1,0
Jack: apparent rate = 44100
Jack: JackDriver::Open capture_driver_name = hw:1,0
Jack: JackDriver::Open playback_driver_name = hw:1,0
Jack: Check protocol client = 8 server = 8
Jack: JackEngine::ClientInternalOpen: name = system
Jack: JackEngine::AllocateRefNum ref = 0
Jack: JackLinuxFutex::Allocate name = jack_sem.0_default_system val = 0
Jack: JackEngine::NotifyAddClient: name = system
Jack: JackGraphManager::SetBufferSize size = 1024
Jack: JackConnectionManager::DirectConnect first: ref1 = 0 ref2 = 0
Jack: JackGraphManager::ConnectRefNum cur_index = 0 ref1 = 0 ref2 = 0
Jack: JackDriver::SetupDriverSync driver sem in flush mode
creating alsa driver ... hw:1,0|hw:1,0|1024|2|44100|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
configuring for 44100Hz, period = 1024 frames (23.2 ms), buffer = 2 periods
ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 16bit little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for capture
ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 16bit little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::Open
Jack: JackServerSocket::Bind : addr.sun_path /dev/shm/jack_default_0_0
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::BuildPoolTable size = 1
Jack: JackEngine::Open
Jack: JackClientSocket::Connect : addr.sun_path /dev/shm/jack_default_0_0
Jack: JackEngine::ClientInternalOpen: name = freewheel
Jack: JackEngine::AllocateRefNum ref = 1
Jack: JackLinuxFutex::Allocate name = jack_sem.0_default_freewheel val = 0
Jack: JackEngine::NotifyAddClient: name = freewheel
Jack: JackDriver::ClientNotify ref = 1 driver = system name = freewheel notify = 0
Jack: JackDriver::ClientNotify ref = 0 driver = freewheel name = system notify = 0
Jack: JackConnectionManager::DirectConnect first: ref1 = 1 ref2 = 1
Jack: JackGraphManager::ConnectRefNum cur_index = 0 ref1 = 1 ref2 = 1
Jack: JackDriver::SetupDriverSync driver sem in flush mode
Jack: JackGraphManager::SetBufferSize size = 1024
Jack: JackAlsaDriver::Attach fBufferSize 1024 fSampleRate 44100
Jack: JackEngine::PortRegister ref = 0 name = system:capture_1 type = 32 bit float mono audio flags = 22 buffer_size = 1024
Jack: JackGraphManager::AllocatePortAux port_index = 1 name = system:capture_1 type = 32 bit float mono audio
Jack: JackConnectionManager::AddOutputPort ref = 0 port = 1
Jack: JackEngine::ClientNotify: no callback for notification = 9
Jack: JackEngine::ClientNotify: no callback for notification = 9
Jack: JackAlsaDriver::Attach fCapturePortList[i] 1
Jack: JackEngine::PortRegister ref = 0 name = system:playback_1 type = 32 bit float mono audio flags = 21 buffer_size = 1024
Jack: JackGraphManager::AllocatePortAux port_index = 2 name = system:playback_1 type = 32 bit float mono audio
Jack: JackConnectionManager::AddInputPort ref = 0 port = 2
Jack: JackEngine::ClientNotify: no callback for notification = 9
Jack: JackEngine::ClientNotify: no callback for notification = 9
Jack: JackAlsaDriver::Attach fPlaybackPortList[i] 2
Jack: JackEngine::PortRegister ref = 0 name = system:playback_2 type = 32 bit float mono audio flags = 21 buffer_size = 1024
Jack: JackGraphManager::AllocatePortAux port_index = 3 name = system:playback_2 type = 32 bit float mono audio
Jack: JackConnectionManager::AddInputPort ref = 0 port = 3
Jack: JackEngine::ClientNotify: no callback for notification = 9
Jack: JackEngine::ClientNotify: no callback for notification = 9
Jack: JackAlsaDriver::Attach fPlaybackPortList[i] 3
Jack: Clock source : system clock via clock_gettime
Jack: JackServer::Start
Jack: JackThreadedDriver::Start
Jack: JackPosixThread::StartImp : create non RT thread
Jack: JackPosixThread::ThreadHandler : start
Jack: JackThreadedDriver::Init real-time
Jack: JackPosixThread::AcquireRealTimeImp priority = 10
Jack: JackPosixThread::StartImp : create non RT thread
Jack: JackPosixThread::ThreadHandler : start
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::ClientCreate socket
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::BuildPoolTable size = 2
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::BuildPoolTable fSocketTable i = 1 fd = 10Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::Execute : fPollTable i = 1 fd = 10
Jack: JackRequest::Notification
............
............
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::Execute : fPollTable i = 1 fd = 10
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::Execute : fPollTable i = 2 fd = 11
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::Execute : fPollTable i = 1 fd = 10
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::Execute : fPollTable i = 2 fd = 11
Jack: JackServer::Stop
Jack: JackThreadedDriver::Stop
Jack: JackPosixThread::Stop
Jack: JackPosixThread::ThreadHandler : exit
Jack: JackPosixThread::Stop
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::Execute : fPollTable i = 1 fd = 10
Jack: JackRequest::Notification
Jack: JackRequest::Notification kQUIT
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::Execute : JackQuitException
Jack: JackPosixThread::ThreadHandler : exit
Jack: JackEngine::ClientNotify: no callback for notification = 15
Jack: JackEngine::ClientNotify: no callback for notification = 15
Jack: JackExternalClient::ClientNotify ref = 2 client = darkice-1551 name = darkice-1551 notify = 15
Jack: JackServer::Close
Jack: JackServerSocket::Close /dev/shm/jack_default_0_0
Jack: JackClientSocket::Close
Jack: JackClientSocket::Close
Jack: JackAudioDriver::Detach
```

Answer (score 1):

you could Start jack with strace to see what the reason is for stopping. Strace is installed by default on raspbian, as far as I am aware of, see https://strace.io